# Is there any way to store 3rd part API keys on AWS other than through secret manager?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-secrets-manager, aws-ssm

I want to store API keys on AWS without having to pay $0.4 a month, also it has to be secure and accessible from Lambda and other functions

I tried secret manager and I want a different solution like s3 maybe?

Comment: You can store it where ever you want. S3 is fine. Is it the best practice? No. But its possible and you can do it if you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can evaluate AWS Parameter Store, this is free charge for Standard parameter and you can encrypt data with a KMS Key specified by yourself for free.

You should pay just 0,05$ each month if there are more than 10.000 API calls (the first 10k are free)

[Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/it/systems-manager/pricing/)

[Difference between Standard and Advanced](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/parameter-store-advanced-parameters.html)

[Encrypt Parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/services-parameter-store.html)